# How can I use scrpage2 with scrartcl?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

For displaying the current section's title in the page-header, I usually use the `scrpage2` package with `scrbook`. However, now I would like to write a report with `scrartcl`, and my settings are not supported anymore: the section is not displayed. Here is the `scrpage2` code, that works with scrbook:

```
\usepackage[%
    headsepline,                %% Separation line below the header
%   footsepline,                %% Separation line above the footer
    markuppercase
]{scrpage2}

 \lefoot{}                      %% Bottom left on even pages
 \lofoot{}                      %% Bottom left on odd pages
 \refoot{}                      %% Bottom right on even pages
 \rofoot{}                      %% Bottom right on odd pages
 \cfoot{}                           %% Bottom center

 \lehead{\bfseries\pagemark}    %% Top left on even pages
 \lohead{\bfseries\headmark}    %% Top left on odd pages
 \rehead{\bfseries\headmark}    %% Top right on even pages
 \rohead{\bfseries\pagemark}    %% Top right on odd pages
 \chead{}                           %% Top center

 \pagestyle{scrheadings}
```

I found [this resource](http://www.komascript.de/faq_automark) (in German), but I do not understand the solution from that. How can I make the packages work with each other?

Comment: The FAQ entry you mention points to [section 4.1.2 of the KOMA-Script documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.pdf#page=131) (English), more information can be found there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some more useful information would have been nice. For the present you can test this.

```
\documentclass[english,twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[%
  automark,
  headsepline,                %% Separation line below the header
%  footsepline,               %% Separation line above the footer
  markuppercase
]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\lehead{\bfseries\pagemark}    %% Top left on even pages
\lohead{\bfseries\headmark}    %% Top left on odd pages
\rehead{\bfseries\headmark}    %% Top right on even pages
\rohead{\bfseries\pagemark}    %% Top right on odd pages
\chead{}                       %% Top center

\automark[subsection]{section}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Further adjustments are left to the interested reader.

As always, the [blindtext](http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext) package is only for creating dummy text thus not part of the solution.

Comment: Thorsten, thank you very much. This worked flawlessly.